# Spring Boot, get queries used to map db extract to POJO

Tags: spring-boot

I wanted to find out if there is a way to know the query Spring Boot creates to extract data from a db.  In detail:  given Spring Boot needs to map a POJO to several tables in a db, how does it create the joints to provide the resulting JSON?  Is there a way to see the query it generates in a log?

Comment: Do you want to show the query generated by Spring Boot /Hibernate in logs?

Comment: Spring JPA by default uses hibernate to fire queries. Enabling the hibernate logs to view the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below configuration in application.properties to see the query generated by Spring Boot / Hibernate

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.*=true
```

You can see the query in console. Here I am sharing a sample of it.

```
2019-07-10 11:46:38:823 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        * 
    from
        user 
    where
        statusenable=true
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        user 
    where
        statusenable=true
```

If you have passed parameters to query you can also see it (last line)

```
2019-07-10 11:49:30:073 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        * 
    from
        user 
    where
        id=? 
        and statusenable=true
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        user 
    where
        id=? 
        and statusenable=true
2019-07-10 11:49:30:089 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [2]
```